# Two fields with same name causing problem in pydantic model classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

I have two `Pydantic` model classes where two fields have the same name as can be seen below:

```
class SnowflakeTable(BaseModel):
    database: str
    schema: str
    table: str
    table_schema: List[SnowflakeColumn]

class DataContract(BaseModel):
    schema: List[OpenmetadataColumn]
```

These model classes have been integrated with other modules to run via `FastAPI` and `Mangum`. Now, when I try hitting the APIs it gives me the below error:

```
NameError: Field name "schema" shadows an attribute in parent "BaseModel"; you might want to use a different field name with "alias='schema'".
```

So, to resolve this I tried using `Field` of Pydantic as below but it didn't work either.

```
class SnowflakeTable(BaseModel):
    database: str
    schema: str = Field(..., alias='schema')
    table: str
    table_schema: List[SnowflakeColumn]
class DataContract(BaseModel):
        schema: List[OpenmetadataColumn] = Field(..., alias='schema')
```

The error remains the same. I tried multiple things w.r.t Fields. Also, tried using Route API but nothing worked. What am I missing here? TIA

P.S. I can't rename the attributes. Thats against the API rules here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the variable names because those names are already in use by pydantic. Try:

```
class SnowflakeTable(BaseModel):
    database: str
    my_var_schema: str = Field(..., alias='schema')
    table: str
    table_schema: List[SnowflakeColumn]

class DataContract(BaseModel):
    my_var_schema: List[OpenmetadataColumn] = Field(..., alias='schema')
```

Don't worry about API fields, if your field has an alias, then fastapi uses the field name in the alias in requests and responses.

More about it:
https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/model_config/#alias-precedence